# How to format input Date using Angular 1.3 and further

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, date, ionic-framework

Developping a mobile app through Ionic, I have this HTML:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="schedule.start"
                   name="startDate"
                   date-to-format />
```

I have this directive aiming to format the rendered date label **within the input**:

```
.directive('dateToFormat', function ($filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                    return data;
                });
                ctrl.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                    return $filter('date')(data, 'EEE dd MMMM yyyy');
                    // error => filter returns a string, not a date object
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

However, since Angular 1.3, formatters has to return a `Date` object rather than the string equivalent.

Typical error using this directive:

```
Expected `mon. 07 september 2015` to be a date.
```

How to format the date using Angular 1.3 and further ?
If I wrap the `$filter` around a `new Date(...)`, I lose the custom format...

Plunkr reproducing the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/eMIHWjtwHSPLxBBYxYu9?p=preview

Comment: Your formatter converts Date value to string, what about your parser? Does it neet to do opposite work (converting string to Date value)?

Comment: Parsers already returns me the corresponding `Date` object.

Comment: You can't reliably change format of the input type date like this. Browser will render locale formatted date in the field. So your directive will be useless in this case.

Comment: I expect passing a Date object from the formatter but displaying in HTML with a custom format.

Comment: You can inject dateFilter service in the controller to format the date. I think no need to create a separate directive for this. If you require I can provide you the code for that

Comment: But I don't want to display it in a distinct label on my page ( a simple filter as you suggest would effectively make the job easily), I expect it to be the **content of my input date**.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: @Varun Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/eMIHWjtwHSPLxBBYxYu9?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

In that case, it's better to use `<input type="text" />` instead of `date` for better browser compatibility. It also prevents Angular from forcing the value to be Date. You can still have custom parsers and formatters in your custom directive.

```
.directive('dateToFormat', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                return new Date(data); // Maybe use some parsing libraries.
            });
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                return $filter('date')(data, 'EEE dd MMMM yyyy');
                // Now you can return strings as you like!
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You would lose the benefit of mobile components, requiring in this case an input date.
https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+select+date&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIsue_8orlxwIVBF4aCh0D-wvt&biw=1285&bih=712#imgrc=ZfCfDQkHVlGkqM%3A

Comment: How about displaying the `<input type="date">` version for touch screens, while still using text for desktops? You can then get the best of both worlds.

Comment: It's a mobile app ;)  ionic Don't bother with desktop.

Comment: Could you please update the question to show that you that you are developing only for mobile and uses the input text only for date display? Otherwise more people like me can get confused and downvoted.

Comment: Regarding desktop also I would downvote, since you would lose any date components that some browsers like Chrome shows off if there is an input date instead of input text.

Comment: You've made your point. But such components often come at a price of the input being restricted to inputting in a certain format, at least it is for me on Chrome 46. That's why I proposed using `type=text` for more flexibility, allowing custom text.

Comment: P.S. I'm not complaining in anyway about the downvote -- as far as I'm concerned, clarifying and then solving the question is more important.